# After change input field with jquery values in rows below are undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm having a table with a number of rows appended based on the number of dates selected. Every row has some input fields with the id's I need to save to a database. If I save the data I loop trough the table with jQuery and save each row, this goes great.

Every row has two dropdowns to select a new value. This value is updated in the input field in that row with this code, this also works great.

```
$(el).closest("tr").find('#locatie_id5').val(locatie_id);
```

The values of this row are also saved correctly. But the row below that only gives the value undefined. Even if I see the right values in the input fields.

What causes the row below to give the wrong values? I don't know how to find the info to debug.

Comment: Are you using the same ID in multiple rows? IDs should be unique, you should use a class.

Comment: The problem is probably in the code that's trying to get all the values, because you have duplicate IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This was part of the solution. So great help